# Changing the constraint of an imageview in a cell programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, autolayout

I really tried to make this thing work. I read alot of articles but non of them gave a proper solution. All I want from xcode is to let me change the top constraint of an imageview in a cell programmatically. I have set my constraints for ipad full screen but I want to adjust few constraints for ipad Pro.

First i tried this:

```
- (void)updateConstraints
{
     [super updateConstraints];
     self.imageViewTopConstraint.constant = 300.f;
} 
- (void)awakeFromNib {
//    // Initialization code
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

and it didnt work.

I then tried to put this line

```
self.imageViewTopConstraint.constant = 300.f;
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Still didnt work. I resized cell height but it didnt work also.

Can you please help me out guys?

P.S: New to xcode.

Million thanks in advance.
[image: This is the custom cell i have created.]

[image: Breakpoint]

[image: Here is the storyboard.]

Comment: How is `imageViewTopConstraint` defined?

Comment: Have you tried [cell updateConstraintIfNeeded]; after changing constraints constant value.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I have connected the iboutlet of nslayoutconstraint in a custom cell class

Comment: @BharatModi didnt work

Comment: There is no solution other than what you have tried or what everyone has suggested. It seems that either you have set constraint incorrectly or you have not connected the constraint outlet properly. Are you getting constraint break log? Also share the screenshot of your cell and the constraint you have set.

Comment: @BharatModi I have updated my questions with the screenshots.

Comment: Show your heightForRowAtIndexPath, you are changing this height constraint in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Right?

Comment: Hi. are you using `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method? are you using storyboard? If so, is the Custom row height property set in the size inspector pane?

Comment: @GoGreen Yes im doing that

Comment: then please uncheck that and try again. this might be the issue. Also, please post the code used in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set imageView's bottom constraint to cell's bottom or chained with label to cell's bottom? And do you receive constraints conflict exceptions? You can add a symbolic breakpoint with symbo: `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`, or search the console output for constraints conflict. If so, you need to adjust constraints and remove one of the bottom constraints.